# How to check if there are multiple versions using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if there are documents with different versions in one group. if so, they should be written into a new dataframe.

My initial dataframe looks as follows:

| document | version | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 1 |
| abc | 1 | 1 |
| abc | 2 | 1 |
| testtest | 4 | 1 |
| xyz | 3 | 2 |
| xyz | 77 | 2 |
| abc | 3 | 3 |
| qwertz | 10 | 4 |
| qwertz | 9 | 4 |
| x | 1 | 5 |
| x | 1 | 5 |

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'document': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'testtest', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'abc', 'qwertz', 'qwertz', 'x', 'x'], 
    'version': [1,1,2,4,3,77,3,10,9,1,1], 
    'group': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

the data frame has a relatively large number of entries. how do I make the performance technically reasonably effective?

Output should be the following:

| group | document | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 |
| 1 | abc | 2 |
| 2 | xyz | 3 |
| 2 | xyz | 77 |
| 4 | qwertz | 10 |
| 4 | qwertz | 9 |

This means that group "2" contains the document "abc" twice in different versions. namely in version "1" and "2". A document that occurs several times in a group but with the same version should not be listed (document "x").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use masks for boolean indexing:

```
# is the full row not duplicated?
m1 = ~df.duplicated()
# is there more that one version per document+group?
m2 = df.groupby(['document', 'group'])['version'].transform('nunique').gt(1)

out = df[m1&m2] # keep if both conditions are met
```

output:

```
  document  version  group
0      abc        1      1
2      abc        2      1
4      xyz        3      2
5      xyz       77      2
7   qwertz       10      4
8   qwertz        9      4
```